# How to put C++ source code snippet into a string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some C++ code snippet in the program. I need to output them when running, such as:

```
int foo()
{
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    string s = "
    int foo()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    ";

    cout << "Code: " << s << endl;
    cout << "Return value: " << foo() << endl;
}
```

I just don't want to copy foo() code into s manually. How to automatically put foo()'s code into s? For example using macro?

Comment: why don't you try the macro approach that you suggest. u can use the `#` stringify operator to add quotes.

Comment: Are you talking about self-printing programs in C? If yes, [here](http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/self_c.txt) you can find a lot of examples (with macroses too).

Answer (score 2):

While this will make your source ugly, you can define the function body in a macro and then stringify it to print.

```
#define FOO\
int foo()\
{\
    return 0;\
}

FOO

#define BASIC_STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) BASIC_STRINGIFY(x)

void main()
{
    string s = STRINGIFY(FOO);

    cout << "Code: " << s << endl;
    cout << "Return value: " << foo() << endl;
}
```